# What do you think about romance between faculty members?

Tags: ethics

Romantic relationships sometimes develop in academic departments between faculty members.

- Has anyone had the experience of developing a romantic relationship with another faculty members? How did you deal with the situation?.
- If you haven't encountered this situation, what do you think about romance between faculty members?
  Is it ethical to develop such a relationship between faculty members, and is it ethical between professor and a post doc in the same department?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I just added my question..sorry. what would you do if you encountered situation that you are attracted to another faculty member?

Comment: Your question is still not yet a good fit for the site. Asking for experiences or general thoughts about a thing is not specific enough. More specific questions might be. Is it ethical? Is it acceptable? When might it be considered sexual harassment? etc. Or you can make your question more specific, i.e., addressing a more particular situation and a particular challenge associated with that.

Comment: Is it ethical?. I included that already in my first statement. So yes that is my question. Also, is romance considered ethical between professor and post doc?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with a romantic relationship between two faculty members as long as one of them doesn't supervise the other. Same thing applies to professor and post doc.

Comment: I suggest choosing one of either faculty-faculty romantic relationships **OR** faculty-postdoc romantic relationships for the focus of your question, not both.

Answer (score 7):

I am not aware of any reputable university (in North America or in other parts of the world with broadly similar cultural mores) in which there are any rules against romantic relationships between faculty.  On the contrary, it is relatively common for faculty members at the same university or in the same department to be married or otherwise openly declared as long term partners.  In most cases the faculty members were in a romantic relationship prior to arriving at the university, but certainly not all.

For the most part, the ethical issues here are the same as for any workplace romance.  The big one of course is:

> One should avoid situations in which the romantic relationship generates a conflict of interest.

Thus for instance it is fairly common for faculty to evaluate each other in various professional capacities: e.g. when it comes to determining annual raises, for tenure and/or promotion, for departmental and university awards of various kinds, and so forth.  One should not take part in the professional evaluation of someone with whom one is engaged in a romantic relationship.  So for instance when in a faculty meeting we are evaluating Professor X whose spouse is Professor Y, then Professor Y leaves the meeting during the evaluation of Professor X, even if she were otherwise entitled to be there.  (If applicable, someone comes to get her afterwards.)

In general, one should arrange work assignments so as to avoid these conflicts of interest.  E.g. if Professor X is a chair of committee A, then his spouse Professor Y should probably not be a member of committee A, if avoidable.  Similarly neither Professor X or Y should be a teaching or research mentor for the other, and so forth.

This brings up the following point:

> A romantic relationship between faculty members should be *declared*, so that conflicts of interest can be avoided.

For instance, if Professor Y is the department head, then some kind of special arrangements need to be made so as not to put herself in a position of power and influence over her spouse Professor X.  Again, it is my understanding that similar practices exist in (at least parts of) the workforce.

Finally, your revised question seems to be asking for anecdotes / advice about starting up romantic relationships with faculty members in your department.  For my part, that is a bit too personal for me to want to relate my experience or lack thereof in this kind of forum.  But I can advise that a romantic relationship with someone for whom one is likely to have a professional relationship spanning years or decades is something that is best done thoughtfully rather than impulsively.  Again, this is really common sense and applies much more generally than just in academia.

Comment: I think what you just mentioned about promotion and peer evaluation is important to keep in mind when considering romance with a colleague, and yes this is true everywhere not only in the academia. To proceed with caution is very important or to avoid it at all if posdible